# Pull from and Push to S3 using Perl

Tags: perl, amazon-s3

everyone!  I have what I assume to be a simple problem, but I could use a hand digging in.  I have a server that preprocesses data before translation.  This is done by a series of perl scripts developed over a decade ago (but they work!).  This virtual server is being lifted into AWS.  The change this makes for my scripts is that the location they pull from and the location they write to will be S3 buckets now.

The work flow is: copy all files in the source location to the local drive, preprocess the data file by file, and when complete move the preprocessed files to a final destination.

```
process_file ($workingDir, $dirEntry);
final_move;
move("$downloadDir/$dirEntry", "$archiveDir") or die "ERROR: Archive file $downloadDir/$dirEntry -> $archiveDir FAILED $!\n";
unlink("$workingDir/$dirEntry");
```

So, in this case $dir and $archiveDir are S3 buckets.

Any advice on adapting this is appreciated.

TIA,

VtR

Comment: *"Push and pull to S3"* : I think you can do that using [Paws](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws)

Comment: See also [Uploading objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html)

Comment: See also [Net::Amazon::S3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::S3)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

- Use a system like [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount your S3 bucket as a local drive. This would presumably require the smallest changes to your existing code.
- Use the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy your files to your S3 bucket.
- Use the Amazon API (through something like [Paws](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws)) to upload your files to S3.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, Dave and Håkon!  Currently conferring with security to determine if I'm allowed to use a git project like s3fs-fuse or a beta SDK like Paws.  Those look like solid options.  I guess a CLI call would work as well.